# Android get all fields using retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I am trying to fetch some fields that I got from JSON. The problem is that if it generates only one then I can get it very easily by using the following

```
[{"sname":"Akshay","class":"MCA","latitude":"73.6562320000","longitude":"72.2041200000"}]
```

by using the following class

```
public class Example {

    @SerializedName("sname")
    @Expose
    private String sname;

    @SerializedName("class")
    @Expose
    private String _class;

    @SerializedName("latitude")
    @Expose
    private String latitude;

    @SerializedName("longitude")
    @Expose
    private String longitude;

    /**
    * 
    * @return
    * The sname
    */
    public String getSname() {
        return sname;
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @param sname
    * The sname
    */
    public void setSname(String sname) {
        this.sname = sname;
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @return
    * The _class
    */
    public String getClass_() {
        return _class;
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @param _class
    * The class
    */
    public void setClass_(String _class) {
        this._class = _class;
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @return
    * The latitude
    */
    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @param latitude
    * The latitude
    */
    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @return
    * The longitude
    */
    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @param longitude
    * The longitude
    */
    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
}
```

But it can generate hundreds of records and I need to fetch them and store in an array
I have no idea how to do it..
example

```
[{"sname":"khfksjd","class":"djfhd","latitude":"73.6562320000","longitude":"72.2041200000"},{"sname":"ak","class":"hdhdh","latitude":"30.1394476766","longitude":"77.2564416164"}{"sname":"dffdf","class":"dfdfdff","latitude":"73.6562320000","longitude":"72.2041200000"},{"sname":"adfdfd","class":"hdxcxchdh","latitude":"30.1394476766","longitude":"77.2564416164"}]
```

can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Just make your method return List<\YourObjectHere> instead of just *YourObject*

Answer (score 0):

1. Create another POJO class like the following.

   ```
   import java.util.ArrayList;

   public class DataExample {

       private ArrayList<Example> arrayList = new ArrayList<Example>();

       public ArrayList<Example> getArrayList() {
           return arrayList;
       }

       public void setArrayList(ArrayList<Example> arrayList) {
           this.arrayList = arrayList;
       }
   }
   ```

I assume that your interface is like this :

```
        @FormUrlEncoded
        @POST("/getExampleData")
        DataExample requestExampleData( @Field("userId") String userId);
```

And in your Activity do the following,

```
 class GetExampleData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                APIRequests request = Utils.getRestAdapter().create(
                        APIRequests.class);
                DataExample mResponseData = request.requestExampleData("userId");
                // Just for understanding purpose.
                //you can get your list by accessing the mResponseData.

                Yourlist = mResponseData.getArrayList();

                // Yourlist now have all the values you need.

            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

thats it. you are good to go!

Comment: @Downvoter. It would be great if you mention why is it downvoted?